# Select range in timestamp from mysql works in phpmyadmin but not in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, timestamp

I have read almost every question i have found here and did not get a solution for my problem.

thing is that my query works in phpMyAdmin search but it does not work in codeigniter query.

here is code From phpMyAdmin that works:

```
SELECT * FROM `pozvani_brojevi` 
WHERE `vrijeme_poziva` 
BETWEEN '2018-04-05 00:00:00' AND '2018-04-26 00:00:00' 
ORDER BY `vrijeme_poziva` DESC
```

and here is code from codeigniter that don't work:

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('pozvani_brojevi');
$this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
$this->db->where("'vrijeme_poziva', BETWEEN 2018-04-05 00:00:00 AND 2018-04-26 00:00:00");
$result = $this->db->get();
$pozvani = $result->result_array();
return $pozvani;
```

note that i have changed code in various ways and always got same result

```
$this->db->where("vrijeme_poziva, BETWEEN 2018-04-05 00:00:00 AND 2018-04-26 00:00:00");

$this->db->where("vrijeme_poziva BETWEEN 2018-04-05 00:00:00 AND 2018-04-26 00:00:00");
```

and i get this error message:

Error Number: 1064

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near '`00:00:00` AND 2018-04-26 00:00:00' at line 4

```
SELECT * FROM `pozvani_brojevi` WHERE `user_id` IS NULL AND `vrijeme_poziva` BETWEEN `2018-04-05` `00:00:00` AND 2018-04-26 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Null as second and FALSE as third parameter as below:

```
$this->db->where(' vrijeme_poziva BETWEEN 2018-04-05 00:00:00 AND 2018-04-26 00:00:00', NULL, FALSE);
```

Another Option that you can use `>=` and `<=` in two separate `where` condition as below:

```
$this->db->where('vrijeme_poziva >=', '2018-04-05 00:00:00');
$this->db->where('vrijeme_poziva <=', '2018-04-26 23:59:59');
```

Comment: Your first option throws same error. And your second option does not have results. and in database there are 5 entries with from 2018-04-25

Comment: just put here result of echo $this->db->last_query();

Comment: Your query was correct. Now i saw that it was looking for user_id IS NULL instead of specific user_id. Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use query method with your sql query like -

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `pozvani_brojevi` WHERE `vrijeme_poziva` BETWEEN '2018-04-05 00:00:00' AND '2018-04-26 00:00:00' ORDER BY `vrijeme_poziva` DESC");
```

For more information refer to https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/queries.html

Comment: i hope this will help you:

$this->db->where(" vrijeme_poziva >= '" . '2018-04-05 00:00:00' . "' AND vrijeme_poziva <= '" . '2018-04-26 23:59:59' . '")->get('pozvani_brojevi')->result_array();

Comment: Same error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '00:00:00 AND 2018-04-26 00:00:00 ORDER BY vrijeme_poziva DESC' at line 1

SELECT * FROM pozvani_brojevi WHERE vrijeme_poziva BETWEEN 2018-04-05 00:00:00 AND 2018-04-26 00:00:00 ORDER BY vrijeme_poziva DESC

Comment: @Damodar did you try $this->db->query()

Comment: @Damodar i have modified the query, try now

Answer (score 0):

```
Hi you can use this query.

$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('pozvani_brojevi');
$this->db->where('user_id', $user_id);
$this->db->where('vrijeme_poziva >=', date('2018-04-05'));
$this->db->where('vrijeme_poziva <=', date('2018-04-26'));
$result = $this->db->get();
$pozvani = $result->result_array();
return $pozvani;
```